# Angular ng-repeat renders view on html based on JSON sent back

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, tile

So I am trying to render what I call a tile. Now all these tile look the same, but the data points displayed will be different depending on particular property called "name". So the JSON looks like so:

```
{
  "beginDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
  "endDate": "2015-12-31T00:00:00",
  "balance": 6989.68,
  "annualAmt": 7200,
  "claimAmt": 210.32,
  "payableAmt": 0,
  "reimbAmt": 210.32,
  "amtToClaim": 0,
  "id": "%2bhnc3gHgwibPEOiPrFKV2g%3d%3d",
  "benefit": "HRAPrime",
  "name": "Preferred Dental Plan (Kennedy)",
  "planTypeId": 4,
  "benefitTypeId": 22,
  "benefitCode": "HRADEN"
},
{
  "balance": 0,
  "ordersPlaced": 0,
  "fundsUsed": 0,
  "lastOrder": 0,
  "currentOrder": 0,
  "currentOrderMonth": "October",
  "lastUpdateDay": "2015-09-20T00:00:00",
  "id": "P06CqlD5cwnLFaxEKvbikA%3d%3d",
  "benefit": "FlexiPass",
  "name": "Flexi-Pass Transit/Vanpool Benefit",
  "planTypeId": 6,
  "benefitTypeId": 29,
  "benefitCode": "FCTRANS"
}
```

So you can see how the data points differ where one data has some properties while another doesn't (very slight). So the render views would kind of look like so:

[image]

You see where one shows 'last date to incur', another doesn't, and so on. Well a logged in user could have several tiles or two. So when the page where these shows renders, it needs to cycle through this and I am sure angular has an easy way to accomplish, but I ain't hitting it so am hoping to get some help here.

So basically, of all the JSON retrieved, some will show, most won't, and then based on the property "name", different  will show or something like that.

Thoughts and help on this please?

If not clear, let me know. I believe what I am looking at is a template or such.

Thanks much.

Comment: are you trying again to ask the same question you asked last week?  In this question, you are at least showing somewhat better what the differences in the data is, but you still aren't really clear what you expect to occur when you don't have these values;  Realistically, you should probably define templates and use a custom directive that chooses the correct template to display, but how many different templates you might need isn't clear enough to write a demo.

Comment: aside from that, using `ng-show` like was mentioned last week and again today seems to satisfy what you are trying to do, assuming you are ok with just empty space in the areas where the data doesn't exist.

Comment: I had thought about how I could do a ng-show based on ng-repeat | name:xxxx. But wasn't sure how that could be. In reality, 4-5 small templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After forking the fiddle provided by @LeoJavier and working in the idea of templates, I came up with a workable example, that could serve as a basis for what you are after.

Key concepts are the two directives and the factory for managing the templates.  In this *trivial* example, the templates are stored inline, but in a production application, the templates would probably each reside in their own file.

The first Directive, `<card>`, serves a very basic purpose, to map an isolate scope on each element to the template, via `ngModel`.

```
App.directive('card', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            item: '=ngModel'
        }
    };
});
```

The next series of directives are each tasked with retrieving a matching template from a template factory. Note in the factory, we are providing the template url as a string into the raw HTML, thus the escaped quotes are necessary.:

```
App.directive('template1', function (templates) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: templates.template1
    };
});

App.directive('template2', function (templates) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: templates.template2
    };
});

App.factory('templates', function () {
    return {
        template1: '<ng-include src="\'template1.html\'"></ng-include>',
        template2: '<ng-include src="\'template2.html\'"></ng-include>'
    };
});
```

Again, in our case, the templates are inline in the HTML.  It is important that the `<script>` tags for the templates are **inside** the element which `ng-app` is on, like so:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Controller">
....
 <!-- template1.html -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
....
</script>

<!-- template2.html -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
....
</script>
</div>
```

As for usage, a simple loop through each of the objects in the array, with an `ng-if` to render the specific template we want for each iteration.

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in data">
    <div ng-if="item.planTypeId==4">
        <card template1 ng-model="item"></card>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="item.planTypeId==6">
        <card template2 ng-model="item"></card>
    </div>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d0x460ge/

Please note that this is only one of many ways that this could be accomplished, and this code is only a proof of concept, and as such could serve with some refactoring.  That being said, I hope this gives you an idea of a possible direction you could take.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/eb20ar4L/

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Controller">
    <div>
        <ul ng-repeat="item in data">
            <li class="title">{{item.name}}</li>
            <li>
                <p>Plan:{{item.benefit}}</p>
                <p class="id">Customer ID:<br/><span>{{item.id}}<span></p>
            </li>
            <li ng-show="item.balance>0">
                <strong>Current balance: </strong>
                <p class="numbers">{{item.balance | currency:"USD$"}}</p>
            </li>
            <li ng-show="item.annualAmt>0">
                <strong>Current balance: </strong>
                <p class="numbers">{{item.annualAmt | currency:"USD$"}}</p>
            </li>
            <li class="date" ng-show="item.lastUpdateDay">
                <p><strong>Date: </strong>{{item.lastUpdateDay}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background:#F2F2F2;;
}
.title{
    background:#333;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:0.8em;
    margin:-20px -20px 20px -20px;
}
ul {
    position:relative;
    height:350px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:thin solid #CCC;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:5px;
    font-family:arial;
}
li{;
    line-height:30px;

}
.numbers{
    margin:0;
    color:#F00;
    font-size:1.5em;
}
.id span{
    background:#E2E2E2;
    color:#555;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:0.8em;
}

.date{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**JS**
var App = angular.module('App', []);

```
App.controller('Controller', function($scope){

    $scope.data = [
{
  "beginDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
  "endDate": "2015-12-31T00:00:00",
  "balance": 6989.68,
  "annualAmt": 7200,
  "claimAmt": 210.32,
  "payableAmt": 0,
  "reimbAmt": 210.32,
  "amtToClaim": 0,
  "id": "%2bhnc3gHgwibPEOiPrFKV2g%3d%3d",
  "benefit": "HRAPrime",
  "name": "Preferred Dental Plan (Kennedy)",
  "planTypeId": 4,
  "benefitTypeId": 22,
  "benefitCode": "HRADEN"
},
{
  "balance": 0,
  "ordersPlaced": 0,
  "fundsUsed": 0,
  "lastOrder": 0,
  "currentOrder": 0,
  "currentOrderMonth": "October",
  "lastUpdateDay": "2015-09-20T00:00:00",
  "id": "P06CqlD5cwnLFaxEKvbikA%3d%3d",
  "benefit": "FlexiPass",
  "name": "Flexi-Pass Transit/Vanpool Benefit",
  "planTypeId": 6,
  "benefitTypeId": 29,
  "benefitCode": "FCTRANS"
}];

});
```

I hope this help man...
https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/eb20ar4L/

Comment: Yes, working on that and was hoping this provided clarity. It boils down to, as a repeat is looping through each object, if the name property is one thing (FSA), it renders a tile one certain data points, if that user has another object, then it renders another tile that lhe tile looks similar, but yes, varies in what it shows. So a user could have 1 tile or 9 tiles. Depends on how many objects are returned.